# Is the LLVM compiler smart enough to remove code within a non-reachable if statement?

Tags: swift, llvm

The following assumes a Swift environment using the LLVM compiler.

GIVEN I have the following:

```swift
var isDebug: Bool {
    #if DEBUG
    return true
    #else
    return false
    #endif
}
```

WHEN the environment flag DEBUG is NOT set
AND the following code is compiled

```swift
var secret = ""
if isDebug {
    secret = "abc123" 
}
print(secret)
```

THEN

1. Will the compiled binary contain the string "abc123" somewhere within it or will the compiler remove it?
2. Is this just as "safe" as using:

```swift
var secret = ""
#if DEBUG
    secret = "abc123" 
#endif
print(secret)
```

Comment: I'm not skilled enough to just answer your question, but you can try it yourself by compiling such Swift file and inspecting the Mach-O binary in a Hopper disassembler.

Answer (score 2):

Based on how you structured it, yes, the compiled code will have your secret, and no, it's not as safe as using conditional compilation block. Reason is that `isDebug` is present *regardless* of the state of conditional compilation block, and hence code inside if will be compiled (it won't be used of course if `DEBUG`, but it will be present).

So you really have to stick to using a conditional compilation block directly, i.e. as in your second example:

```
var secret = ""
#if DEBUG
    secret = "abc123" 
#endif
```

But also looking at your use case (i.e. secrets), the problem here is not just that compiled code may or may not contain your secret, it's also [a bad idea to store secrets in the code](https://www.google.com/search?q=why%20storing%20secrets%20in%20code%20is%20a%20bad%20idea&oq=why%20storing%20secrets%20in%20code%20is%20a%20bad%20idea&aqs=chrome..69i57.7301j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - whether you are using github, or internal source control.

Instead, you can *inject* your secret at build time, retrieving it from the safe store. There are many options, one of the simplest ones is putting a secret into PLIST, and storing it securely away from source code, and retrieving it at compilation time if it's needed. [Here is a good tutorial](https://nshipster.com/secrets/) on this and some other options

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kiril S. I was hoping to avoid using #if DEBUG  as it is as safe as checking for a string at runtime, as opposed to a defined property. As for the use case, that was for demonstration purposes, I agree secrets should be stored externally 

Comment: I don’t know anything about Swift but since this question is about LLVM, I think the answer is wrong. This is a trivial dead code elimination that LLVM performs as par for the course even on low optimisation levels. However, this depends on whether LLVM can infer that `isDebug` is a constant, in which case it will first perform constant folding, transforming the code into (effectively) `if false {…}`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The question was "_Is this just as "safe"_", and the answer is definitely "No".  Conditional compilation block gives you a guarantee that code won't be compiled and will not exist in final version of compiled code. Relying on compiler optimization does not give you any guarantees. Maybe I should have considered it as an unreliable possibility, like explained in the other answer, but I looked at this question I guess more from security perspective, so didn't think about possible optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

It might be removed when compiled with `-O`, but there is no promise of this behavior. You can demonstrate that for this trivial code, it does work:

```
% swift --version
swift-driver version: 1.26.9 Apple Swift version 5.5.1 (swiftlang-1300.0.31.4 clang-1300.0.29.6)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx12.0

% cat x.swift
var isDebug: Bool {
    #if DEBUG
    return true
    #else
    return false
    #endif
}

var secret = ""
if isDebug {
    secret = "abc123"
}
print(secret)

% swiftc x.swift && strings x | grep abc123
abc123

% swiftc -O x.swift && strings x | grep abc123
%
```

But this code is particularly simple and easy for the optimizer. There is no promise that arbitrary code will optimize this way, and there's no promise that future versions of the compiler will optimize this way.